# Why isn't my function being ran in my program (java)?

Tags: java, function, maze

The program is supposed to solve a maze recursively. the readMazeFile reads the contents of a file into an array, then the solveMaze function uses that array to solve the maze. but in my main function nothing past if (maze != null) does not seem to be running. I included that to get rid of the null pointer exception. Does maze = null? i did not think so but idk. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
public class solving {
    static char maze[][];
    static int startingrow;
    static int startingcol;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        readMazeFile("maze0.txt");
        if (maze != null) {
            System.out.print(maze[1][1]);

            if (solveMaze(startingrow, startingcol))
                System.out.print("Solved!");
            else
                System.out.print("There is no solution to this maze.");
        }
    }

    static boolean solveMaze(int row, int col) {
        // name each movement to make coding easier to understand with the recursion.
        char right = maze[row][col + 1];
        char left = maze[row][col - 1];
        char up = maze[row - 1][col];
        char down = maze[row + 1][col];
        char markSpot = 'M';
        char unmarkSpot = ' ';

        // Base case is at the end of the maze
        if (right == 'E' || left == 'E' || up == 'E' || down == 'E') {
            return true;
        }

        // What to do if there is an empty space when it moves
        if (right == ' ') {
            right = markSpot;
            if (solveMaze(row, col + 1)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                right = unmarkSpot;
            }
        }

        if (down == ' ') {
            down = markSpot;
            if (solveMaze(row + 1, col)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                up = unmarkSpot;
            }
        }

        if (left == ' ') {
            left = markSpot;
            if (solveMaze(row, col - 1)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                left = unmarkSpot;
            }
        }

        if (up == ' ') {
            up = markSpot;
            if (solveMaze(row - 1, col)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                up = unmarkSpot;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static char[][] readMazeFile(String mazeFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));

        // Find the height and width
        int height = input.nextInt();
        int width = input.nextInt();
        int finalHeight = (2 * height) + 1;
        int finalWidth = (2 * width) + 1;

        // Create the array and put data from the file in it
        char maze[][] = new char[finalHeight][finalWidth];
        input.nextLine();

        for (int row = 0; row < finalHeight; row++) {
            String fileLine = input.nextLine();
            for (int col = 0; col < finalWidth; col++) {
                char nextChar = fileLine.charAt(col);
                maze[row][col] = nextChar;
            }
        }

        // Find the starting point
        for (int r = 0; r < finalHeight; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < finalWidth; c++) {
                if (maze[r][c] == 'S') {
                    int startingrow = r;
                    int startingcol = c;
                    //System.out.print(startingrow);
                    //System.out.print(startingcol);
                }
            }
        }

        return maze;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it will be null to me. Why do you think it wouldn't be null?

Comment: `readMazeFile` cannot return null (good), so there's no point attempting to do a null-check on it. It just adds noise. But since you're not storing the return value anyway, you're simply checking the shadowed `maze`, which is never instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

The `maze` variable in `readMazeFile` shadows the static variable you're using in the conditional.

Either:

- Assign the result of `readMazeFile`.
- Don't declare a new `maze` variable in `readMazeFile` (remove the `char` type declarator). Returning it then becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the result of your function call in the first line of your main to the variable maze. Since you have not done this, maze is of course null.